# Python3 - IndexError when trying to save a text file

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, function, text, cntk

i'm trying to follow this tutorial with my own local data files:

[CNTK tutorial](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/CNTK_103A_MNIST_DataLoader.html)

i have the following function to save my data array into a txt file feedable to CNTK:

```
# Save the data files into a format compatible with CNTK text reader

def savetxt(filename, ndarray):
    dir = os.path.dirname(filename)

    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)

    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("Saving", filename )
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            labels = list(map(' '.join, np.eye(11, dtype=np.uint).astype(str)))
            for row in ndarray:
                row_str = row.astype(str)
                label_str = labels[row[-1]]
                feature_str = ' '.join(row_str[:-1])
                f.write('|labels {} |features {}\n'.format(label_str, feature_str))
    else:
        print("File already exists", filename)
```

i have 2 ndarrays of the following shape that i want to feed the model:

```
train.shape
(1976L, 15104L)

test.shape
(1976L, 15104L)
```

Then i try to implement the fucntion like this:

```
# Save the train and test files (prefer our default path for the data)

data_dir = os.path.join("C:/Users", 'myself', "OneDrive", "IA Project", 'data', 'train')
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    data_dir = os.path.join("data", "IA Project")

print ('Writing train text file...')
savetxt(os.path.join(data_dir, "Train-128x118_cntk_text.txt"), train)

print ('Writing test text file...')
savetxt(os.path.join(data_dir, "Test-128x118_cntk_text.txt"), test)

print('Done')
```

and then i get the following error:

```
Writing train text file...
Saving C:/Users\A702628\OneDrive - Atos\Microsoft Capstone IA\Capstone data\train\Train-128x118_cntk_text.txt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b53d3c69b8d2> in <module>()
      6 
      7 print ('Writing train text file...')
----> 8 savetxt(os.path.join(data_dir, "Train-128x118_cntk_text.txt"), train)
      9 
     10 print ('Writing test text file...')

<ipython-input-23-610c077db694> in savetxt(filename, ndarray)
     12             for row in ndarray:
     13                 row_str = row.astype(str)
---> 14                 label_str = labels[row[-1]]
     15                 feature_str = ' '.join(row_str[:-1])
     16                 f.write('|labels {} |features {}\n'.format(label_str, feature_str))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can somebody please tell me what's going wrong with this part of the code? And how could i fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using your own input data -- are they labelled in the range 0 to 9? The labels array only has 10 entries in it, so that could cause an out-of-range problem.

Comment: Hi @Ho John Lee, thanks for your answer. No in fact, i have 11 classes. 0 to 9. Do you think that can be the problem? If so, how could i fix it?

Comment: If your class labels are really only 0 to 9, then your code shouldn't be seeing something that is causing an index out of range. Is your data formatted to put the label at the end of the array (index "-1"). Maybe take a look and see what's the value that's out of bounds at that point.

Comment: Hi @Ho John Lee, i made a typo above, i have 11 classes 0 to 10. Basically i don't  see any problems with the data, it is exaclty the same way it was in the CNTK MNIST tutorial. Anyway index -1 is just a flag to indicate the labels go at the end, you can index anything with `:-1` that's why i don't understand the why of this error. If `:-1` don't work, what could i put at its place?